# Error: XML Serialization of a field of type object when set to an array

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am attempting to serialise a class (Config) that holds a field (type objet) that holds a data item class (MyDataItem). The `MyDataItem` class holds a field (type object) to hold the data item's value (value). The reason that the value is of type object is that a `MyDataItem` could possible hold values of different types. When this value is set to an array (ex int []) instead of a basic type (int, string etc), I get a `System.Invalid operation exception` error:

```
There was an error generating the XML document.
The type System.Int32[] may not be used in this context.
```

Does anyone know how i could resolve this?

I am working on windows XP, Visual studio 2008 and .net 3.5

Sample program showing the error:

http://pastebin.com/esv55AvC

Answer (score 0):

Not my recommendation (IMO you should have very simple, obvious POCO / DTO models), but this should work:

```
    [XmlElement("tmp", Type = typeof(MyDataItem))]
    public object tmp;
```

and:

```
    [XmlElement("Foo", Type = typeof(int[]))]
    [XmlElement("Bar", Type = typeof(int))]
    public object Value;
```